# Iteration in r for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach, iterator

I want to write a `for` loop that iterates over a `vector` or `list`, where i'm adding values to them in each iteration. i came up with the following code, it's not iterating more than 1 iteration. i don't want to use a `while` loop to write this program. I want to know how can i control for loops iterator. thanks in advance.

```
steps <- 1
random_number <- c(sample(20, 1))
for (item in random_number){
  if(item <18){
    random_number <- c(random_number,sample(20, 1))
    steps <- steps + 1
  }
}
print(paste0("It took ", steps, " steps."))
```

Comment: Your code `sample(20, 1)` creates only a single random number. That is why the loop only goes through one iteration because `for`  expects a vector of items to loop through. If you want more than one random number use `ample(20, n)` with being your desired value `n >1`.

Comment: @Jan thanks for your comment. I know, the main problem is about writing a for loop in order to iterate over a dynamic vector. if you dynamically add values to a vector, this for loop will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done. The vector used in the `for` loop is evaluated at the start of the loop and any changes to that vector won't affect the loop. You will have to use a `while` loop or some other type of iteration.

Comment: Agreed. `for´ is not the appropriate control structure for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It depends really on what you want to achieve. Either way, I am afraid you cannot change the iterator on the fly. `while` seems resonable in this context, or perhaps knowing the plausible maximum number of iterations, you could proceed with those, and deal with needless iterations via an if statement. Based on your code, something more like:

```
steps <- 1

for (item in 1:100){
  random_number <- c(sample(20, 1))
  if(random_number < 18){
    random_number <- c(random_number,sample(20, 1))
    steps <- steps + 1
  }
}
print(paste0("It took ", steps, " steps."))
```

Which to be honest is not really different from a `while()` combined with an if statement to make sure it doesn't run forever.